# Which one drains more battery: listen to volume change or accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-mediaplayer

My app need to play music whenever user want even in screen off mode. I know 2 ways to do it:
- Use a fake MediaPlayer with volume = 0 to listening to volume button.
- Use accelerometer to dectect shake.

so, which one drains more battery? which one i should choose? Is there any other way?
Thanks for ur helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accelerometer will be more battery intensive.  If nothing else is using it, it will need to be turned on which costs power.  If something is using it, you'll be receiving regular updates which will take more CPU power to process than a single message when a button is actually pushed.

Answer (score 0):

accelerometer drains more battery, because sensor needs more resources of device as compare to Media Player.